# What is the origin of the phrase "when life gives you lemons, make lemonade"?

Tags: phrases, etymology

I tried to find the etymology of the cliche "when life gives you lemons, make lemonade" on the Internet, but so far I haven't had any luck. It won't even tell me if it's a maxim or not.

Comment: Can you have an etymology of a cliche?

Comment: You have to look up "origin" or "history" for phrases, idioms and proverbs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dale Carnegie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Carnegie) popularized the cliché, but I found it in print five years prior to Carnegie's first publication. This is from a [sidebar of maxims](http://books.google.com/books?id=AypRAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=lemonade&f=false) in a men's clothing advertising periodical called *Men's Wear*, 1908/09:

> In business turn obstacles into conveniences. When handed a lemon—make lemonade of it.

This reference most likely precludes Carnegie from being the phrase's progenitor as he was [selling lard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Carnegie#Biography) at the time of its publication.

It seems Carnegie did not use the phrase in print until his last of six books, published in 1948, *How to Stop Worrying and Start Living*, in which he has a chapter titled "[If You Have a Lemon, Make a Lemonade](http://books.google.com/books?id=EVq1iCtjZuAC&dq=%22how%20to%20stop%20worrying%20and%20start%20living%22&q=lemonade#v=onepage&q=lemonade&f=false)" that ends with his *Rule #6*:

> When fate hands us a lemon, let's try to make a lemonade.

Comment: The *Men's Wear* book actually appears to be from 1910: search for 1910 in the book, and you'll find a New Years greeting from that year.

Comment: @Peter: Read the first paragraph of that [greeting](http://books.google.com/books?id=AypRAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=1910&f=false).

Comment: @hippietrail: My "selling lard" link goes to the same place, but your placement makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcom Callithumpian - sorry I didn't spot your link.

Comment: Carnegie used the meaning of "lemon" as a useless item, and linked it back to its original meaning as a useful fruit. What I don't know is where the "useless item" meaning came from. Hence: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/why-lemon-for-a-faulty-or-defective-item

Comment: @slim I always thought of 'lemon' here as 'bitter': when life gives you something bitter, make something sweet out of it. I never read Carnegie though.

Answer (score 3):

It is widely attributed to Dale Carnegie. There's a wikipedia entry for it. It may be older than him, and he may have merely popularized it. Google "carnegie lemonade" and see what shakes out for you.

Comment: +1; I was unable to find an actual _source_, but the original Carnegie quote appears to be "When fate hands you a lemon, make lemonade."

Comment: @MrHen: Right. Normally I would post a link, but none of them seemed authoritative enough to label as a solid cite. Nevertheless, it does appear that the quote is widely attributed to Carnegie. Before looking, I was half expecting Erma Bombeck to be the source.

Comment: I did find one person thinking it was H.J. Whitley but no other hits for that search at all.

Comment: Lemonade should be stirred, not shaken.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the saying is originally attributed to Elbert Hubbard:
"A genius is a man who takes the lemons that Fate hands him and starts a lemonade stand with them."
(Reader's Digest, October 1927) [ref](http://books.google.com/books?id=ct6t4TDce04C&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=dale%20carnegie%20lemon%20make%20lemonade&source=bl&ots=BBnyNYio7a&sig=e1tygzbMYEc0M6R_6BpRFkiDYc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YtcpUO-1MufmiwKt-oDQAQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=dale%20carnegie%20lemon%20make%20lemonade&f=false)

However, the saying is usually credited to Dale Carnegie, who published it as:
"When fate hands us a lemon let's try to make a lemonade."
(Rule #6, at the end of Chapter 17 in Carnegie's "How to Stop Worrying and Start Living" published in 1948)

EDIT: Probing a little further, I acquired the [October, 1927 "Reader's Digest"](http://archive.org/details/ReadersDigestno.66October1927). As foretold, I discovered Hubbard's "lemon quote", right there on page 343, borrowed from "The Independent".

Answer (score 0):

It was H J Whitley who the phrase was coined about. In the early 1900 he bought 500 acres in the heart of Hollywood.  He turned lemon orchards into Hollywood.  At a banquet his business partners toasted him saying if life gives you lemons make lemonade.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please consider adding references to your answer. For example, cite a dictionary entry, or quote a paragraph where this is used in context.