# Idioms: Exploiting/Taking Advantage of Others (negative connotation)

Tags: expressions, idioms, popular-refrains, proverbs

Could you please give me an idiom, proverb, or saying that describes someone who **exploits** and **take advantage** of others?

An idiomatic expression that has a negative connotation.

Or maybe to say that one only pray when he/she needs God.

Or something similar to this (I quit praying when I got my prayers answered).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/156518/365490

Comment: Such a person **_uses_ others** [as if they were merely tools, instruments with no rights and no feelings, merely to be left on the shelf when finished with].

Comment: One example of this is 'an employer who forces his employees to work long hours/overtime, but doesn't pay very much.'

Answer (score 0):

**User** is what you’re looking for. Third definition.
[image]