# Are there good alternatives to "making the best of a bad situation?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Life is full of adversity, and people facing challenging life circumstances have to find a way to cope. I'm interested in single words, phrases, or idioms that capture coping strategies. For example:

> Jane's job was absurdly repetitive and oppressive, but for her family, she tried to *make the best of a bad situation*.

Are there good alternatives to the coping strategy of *making the best of bad situation*?

**Clarification**: I am looking for alternatives, especially idioms, that don't involve words like *good* and *bad*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## to sweeten the bitter pill

> To make something bad, unpleasant, or dissatisfactory [easier to cope with](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sweeten+the+pill), endure, or accept.

“Jane's job was absurdly repetitive and oppressive, but for her family, she sweetened the bitter pill as much as possible.”

I suppose you could also say that Jane had no choice but to **[swallow the bitter pill](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-bitter-pill-to-swallow)**. In other words, she was left with no choice but to accept her lot (situation) in life.

Comment: In my example, I am imagining that the *bitter pill* is administered every day over a long period of time, and no one is making an effort to sweeten it. It's not like the following examples from your reference: (1) *The bosses are giving everyone an extra 10% bonus this Christmas, but I suspect it's a way of sweetening the pill that there will be massive pay cuts in January.* (2) *I have to tell my mom about wrecking her car, but I need to find a way to sweeten the pill first.*

Comment: I suppose you could say that she had no choice but to **swallow the bitter pill,** in other words she was left with no choice but to  accept her lot (situation) without grumbling.

Comment: Sounds like *acceptance*. :-) Yes, that would definitely be a coping strategy. Much healthier and more productive than fighting  a losing battle day in and day out. Would you mind folding it into your answer?

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, I was referring to adding something to the effect of *having no choice but to **swallow the bitter pill***, where **swallowing the bitter pill** amounts to accepting one's situation. This was the essence of your comment. Hope you enjoy your visit.

Answer (score 4):

1. *To make lemonade out of lemons*.

> - Lemons are sour.
> - Lemonade is sweet
>
> **To make lemonade out of lemons** is to take something that is not so great and turn it into something good — [**ELU**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75929/what-does-turn-a-lemons-into-lemonade-exactly-mean)

---

> **When life gives you lemons, make lemonade** is a proverbial phrase used to encourage optimism and a positive can-do attitude in the face of adversity or misfortune. Lemons suggest sourness or difficulty in life; making lemonade is turning them into something positive or desirable — [**Wikipedia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade)

<sup>I didn't find any dictionary definition but I've heard this idiom and used it myself.</sup>

---

2. *To find a silver lining*.

> **Silver lining:** An advantage that comes from a difficult or unpleasant situation.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/silver-lining)

**Example:** Jane's job was absurdly repetitive and oppressive, but for her family, she tried to *find a silver lining*/ *make lemonade out of lemons*.

Comment: I like the version from Portal 2... “When life gives you lemons, don’t make lemonade! Make life take the lemons back! Get mad! I don’t want your damn lemons; what am I supposed to do with these? Demand to see life’s manager! Make life rue the day it thought it could give Cave Johnson lemons! Do you know who I am? I’m the man who’s gonna burn your house down... with lemons! I’m gonna get my engineers to invent a combustible lemon that burns your house down!”

Answer (score 2):

A search on [Linguee.com](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/al+mal+tiempo+buena+cara.html) for translations from a Spanish proverb, "a mal tiempo, buena cara", which literally translates to "to bad weather, [give] a good face", led me to the following idiomatic options:

- To **make the best of a bad job**: "But if these elections do go ahead - if the government insists on them going ahead - we, Labour, are determined to make the best of a bad job." — [**BBC**](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-18491390)
- To **put a  good face on things** "Yet there they all were at Carnegie Hall, not only putting a good face on things but also doing their best." — **[NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2004/05/07/world/spanish-premier-says-troops-will-not-return-to-iraq.html)**

Comment: See my comment above. Sorry for not making the question clearer. This are both good answers.

Answer (score 1):

### make hay

For something that's a short verbal phrase, and almost in line with the single-word request of the question, try **make hay**.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*make*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *make hay*
>   : to make use of a situation or circumstance especially in order to gain an advantage
>   // The candidate *made hay* of his opponent's scandalous behavior.

As a regular verbal phrase, it has the advantage of being more versatile than the other *x of y* or *to x the y* forms of similar sayings.

The example sentence in the question could be shortened considerably with this:

> Jane's job was absurdly repetitive and oppressive, but for her family, she tried to *make hay*.

---

An additional reference for this is from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+hay):

> To take advantage; to make the most of an opportunity.
>   *Chicago better be careful about turnovers, or you can be sure the defending champs will make hay in those situations.*
>   *We'll be able to make hay with so little traffic on the road.*
>    … This is a shortened version of the proverb *make hay while the sun shines*, which dates from the mid 16th century.

Comment: I'm not sure *making hay* is a strategy for coping with life challenges. It seems to be more about taking advantage of opportunities or using situations to gain an advantage. My example concerned a person not likely to be presented with any opportunities or situations that would enable her to gain an advantage. Hard to see a way for her to *make hay*.

Answer (score 0):

How about **maintain a stiff upper lip**. From Lexico:

> **[a stiff upper lip](https://www.lexico.com/definition/a_stiff_upper_lip)**: a quality of uncomplaining stoicism

This sort of mindset strikes me as an effective strategy for dealing with challenging life circumstances unlikely to change.