# What is the contradictory proverb to "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, contradiction

Sweet lemons and sour grapes tend to be used by people who have a reactionary outlook on life.  They reason that things are just the way they are and we are bound to our circumstance.  They will often use the phrase "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade" because they deem that people's outer experience is highly uncontrollable but we can only control our subjective selves and make the best with what we are helplessly given from our outer experience.

There is the opposite kind of thinking though that will never use such a phrase and finds it weak and pitiful to allow experiences to toss us around.  If you had gotten lemons and were left only with the option to at best make lemonade, you are already too late.  You should have not allowed life to give you lemons in the first place.

Often parables can be argued against with another parable; as in, "Look before you leap." Vs "He who hesitates is lost."

What is the contradictory parable to "When life gives you lemons, make lemonade."?

The phrase would carry the meaning of instead of letting life dictate your options, you be the boss of life and make it serve your desired ideal.

Comment: A cut lemon standing out between two grey lemons and against a grey background
When life gives you lemons, make lemonade is *a proverbial phrase used to encourage optimism and a positive can-do attitude in the face of adversity or misfortune.* Lemons suggest sourness or difficulty in life, just like lemonade. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22588/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-when-life-gives-you-lemons-make-lemonade

Comment: I don't understand the lemons and lemonade proverb in the way you do at all. You aren't forced to make the lemonade, you choose to make it: you can then enjoy it yourself or sell it for a profit. The proverb tells you to look for the opportunities in misfortune. You can't always prevent bad things from happening to you but you can find positives when they do. There won't be an opposite proverb because it would imply the attitude of gloomy acceptance you dislike and proverbs aren't like that. The nearest I can think of is the comic "If at first you don't succeed, give up!"

Comment: How about, "When someone presents you with a horse as a gift, check its teeth"?

Comment: @BoldBen, There are the types who seek to look for opportunities in misfortune but there are also the types who believe that all misfortune is a fault that should have been prevented.  There are proverbs that promote this idea.  I am asking for them.  The idea that bad things cannot always be prevented is an opinion.  There are people who do not share it.  These types of people find the make lemons idiom pathetic because you should have avoided the lemons in the first place.  Serves you right for now having to do something with them.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson, your understanding of the _lemons_ proverb is unique to you (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade) - and previously linked in the comments - the phrase has an interesting origin, all else aside). As it stands, your question will likely mislead potential answerers. You might do better to edit _lemons_ out of your question entirely, if what you want is to get an answer to your actual question.

Comment: Thank you all.  I have updated the question to include the idea of  "The proverb tells you to look for the opportunities in misfortune."  The opposing view is that misfortune is always your fault and you should not have allowed it.

Comment: I once heard "If God gives you lemons... get a new religion!" But that's not a proverb, it's a joke.

Comment: I think the proverb, "Mind over matter" and "Believe it and you can achieve it" Are some examples of the idioms that I was looking for.  One type of person seeks optimism in the face of disaster, while the other type seeks to organize life in such a way that disaster would never happen, and if it did, they blame themselves.  For them, to make lemonade is pointless and they simply need to learn from the mistake and scrap the lemons and start from scratch.  They are the Mind over matter type.  "When life gives you lemons, you know you weren't good enough."

Comment: *Play the cards you're dealt* doesn't seem far off the "make lemonade" meaning.  You want something machiavellian about finding any means to the intended ends, maybe?

Comment: My immediate thought upon reading the title was, “When lemons give you life, make… erm, lifade?”. I’m sure it’ll catch on.

Comment: Perhaps instead of (passively) letting life give you lemons, you should (actively) *take the bull by the horns* And change the situation?

Comment: A word request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: For advice on writing, writing styles, or academic standards, one of these other sites might be helpful: [academia.se], [writers.se], [literature.se], [workplace.se], [interpersonal.se]. If you want to try another site, please ask for migration, or else delete here before re-asking the question on the other site.

Answer (score 2):

**make hay while the sun shines** or just **make hay**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hay) idioms

> To take advantage of favorable conditions; to make the most of an
>   opportunity when it is available!

As in:

> We finally have the full group assembled, so let's make hay while the
>   sun shines and get this thing done.

Comment: I was going to suggest this in the comments, because it fits the question (shining sun as apposed to getting lemons) but I'm not at all sure it fits what the OP wants, which seems to be an idiom about bending nature to your will good or bad.  I think.  Or maybe complete ownership of all outcomes.  +1 regardless.

Answer (score 0):

***A stitch in time saves nine***.  According to [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-stitch-in-time.html), this means

> A timely effort will prevent more work later.

***An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure*** means the same thing.  Benjamin Franklin was talking about fire safety, according to the [University of Cambridge](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/ounce-of-prevention-pound-of-cure):

> Benjamin Franklin famously advised fire-threatened Philadelphians in
>   1736 that “An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.”

Both these expressions say that it is better to be proactive than reactive.  For example, if you have a fire that burns down your house, the lemons/lemonade saying advises you use the opportunity a house fire (a lemon) gives you to get rid of junk and replace the things you dislike with things you like (the lemonade).  (This example assumes you have fire insurance.)  The two sayings I offered advises you to, e.g., modernize the electrical system in your house and not smoke in bed.